# General Fizzbuzz

Tags: fizzbuzz, rust

I'm learning Rust now and created a program to solve the task [General Fizzbuzz on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/General_FizzBuzz).

For example, given:

```
20
3 Fizz
5 Buzz
7 Baxx
```

where the first line indicates the upper bound and every line after that indicates the divisor and the corresponding word, the program should return:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
Baxx
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
Baxx
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```

The code is as follows:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn parse_entry(l: &str) -> (i32, String) {
    let params: Vec<&str> = l.split(' ').take(2).collect();

    let divisor = params[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let word = params[1].to_string();
    (divisor, word)
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());

    let l = lines.next().unwrap();
    let high = l.parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    let mut entries = Vec::new();
    for l in lines {
        let entry = parse_entry(&l);
        entries.push(entry);
    }

    for i in 1..(high + 1) {
        let mut line = String::new();
        for &(divisor, ref word) in &entries {
            if i % divisor == 0 {
                line = line + &word;
            }
        }
        if line == "" {
            println!("{}", i);
        } else {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like feedback on improving the readability of this code and making it more concise. Is there a better way to parse the input, or to access the entries?

Comment: Have you seen the [**excellent** blog post](http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html) by Chris Morgan about FizzBuzz in Rust?

Comment: @Shepmaster I have not, thanks for that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I added some stub variables so I could run the code in the [Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/):

```
let z = ["20", "3 Fizz", "5 Buzz", "7 Baxx"];
let mut lines = z.iter().map(|s| s.to_string());
```

Next, I have a dislike for specifying the type in a function call, and prefer to just specify the type of the variable:

```
// let high = l.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
let high: i32 = l.parse().unwrap();
```

I also wanted to see if I could remove the temporary variable. I *did*, but not so sure it makes it better:

```
let high: i32 = lines.next().and_then(|l| l.parse().ok()).unwrap();
```

I then replaced manual loop management with a functional-style `map`. This has the *great* benefit of not requiring the `entries` vector to be mutable. I find it's often a good idea to constrain the mutability to as small as possible. I also don't like specifying types that the compiler can infer for me. In this case, I use `Vec<_>` instead of `Vec<(i32, String)>`. `_` is used to denote "I don't care", both in types and in variable names (such as for an unused variable):

```
// let mut entries = Vec::new();
// for l in lines {
//     let entry = parse_entry(&l);
//     entries.push(entry);
// }

let entries: Vec<_> = lines.map(|l| parse_entry(&l)).collect();
```

I did a similar thing for the inner loop of joining strings:

```
// let mut line = String::new();
// for &(divisor, ref word) in &entries {
//     if i % divisor == 0 {
//         line = line + &word;
//     }
//  }

let line: String = entries.iter()
    .filter(|&&(divisor, _)| i % divisor == 0)
    .map(|&(_, ref word)| &word[..])
    .collect();
```

I then wanted to give a bit of structure (pun half intended) to the data:

```
struct Entry {
    divisor: i32,
    word: String,
}

impl Entry {
    fn matches(&self, val: i32) -> bool { val % self.divisor == 0 }
    fn word(&self) -> &str { &self.word }
}
```

Which makes the inner loop look like:

```
let line: String = entries.iter()
    .filter(|entry| entry.matches(i))
    .map(Entry::word)
    .collect();
```

I then moved `parse_entry` to an implementation of `FromStr`. This will allow `Entry` to participate in the fun that is `str::parse`:

```
impl str::FromStr for Entry {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Entry, ()> {
        let params: Vec<&str> = s.split(' ').take(2).collect();

        let divisor = params[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        let word = params[1].to_string();
        Ok(Entry { divisor: divisor, word: word })
    }
}
```

The "downside" is that parsing an entry can now fail, and so we have to deal with that. Really, there's an `unwrap` call in there that truly does indicate failure, so that should be addressed:

```
let entries: Result<Vec<Entry>, ()> = lines.map(|l| l.parse()).collect();
let entries = entries.unwrap();
```

Here's my final code:

```
use std::{io,str};
use std::io::BufRead;

struct Entry {
    divisor: i32,
    word: String,
}

impl Entry {
    fn matches(&self, val: i32) -> bool { val % self.divisor == 0 }
    fn word(&self) -> &str { &self.word }
}

impl str::FromStr for Entry {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Entry, ()> {
        let params: Vec<_> = s.split(' ').take(2).collect();

        let divisor: i32 = params[0].parse().unwrap();
        let word = params[1].to_string();
        Ok(Entry { divisor: divisor, word: word })
    }
}

fn main() {
    //let stdin = io::stdin();
    //let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());

    let z = ["20", "3 Fizz", "5 Buzz", "7 Baxx"];
    let mut lines = z.iter().map(|s| s.to_string());

    let high: i32 = lines.next().and_then(|l| l.parse().ok()).unwrap();

    let entries: Result<Vec<Entry>, ()> = lines.map(|l| l.parse()).collect();
    let entries = entries.unwrap();

    for i in 1..(high + 1) {
        let line: String = entries.iter()
            .filter(|entry| entry.matches(i))
            .map(Entry::word)
            .collect();

        if line.is_empty() {
            println!("{}", i);
        } else {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent feedback! Just a question,  why is the redeclaration of `entries` allowed, and what does `Vec(_)` mean?

Comment: @wei2912 It's very hard to answer **why** something is allowed. The "answer" is *because Rust allows it*. Unless you want me to make speculation about the hopes and desires of the Rust core team, perhaps you can reword your question? I'll update my answer to describe `Vec<_>`.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask about under what conditions is redeclaration allowed. Is it generally allowed in Rust or are there restrictions?

Comment: @wei2912 gotcha. Yes, redeclaration of variables is generally allowed. I'm always a little surprised that you can even [redeclare something that is borrowed](http://is.gd/LWyg4m). Under the hood, the owned variable must still be tracked by the compiler, it's just not available to the programmer anymore.